# ambiguous type error when using type families, and STV is not helping

Tags: haskell, ambiguous, type-families

```
{-# LANGUAGE Haskell2010 #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class PoC m where
    type Wrapper m :: * -> *
    wrap :: l -> Wrapper m l
```

I'm working with haskell-src-exts, and I want to upgrade my AST to have freshly generatable labels. Since I want to do it in an extensible fashion, I created an interface like the code above. However, code to upgrade the AST doesn't work. I have the following:

```
upgrade :: forall f m l. (PoC m, Functor f) => f l -> f (Wrapper m l)
upgrade x = fmap (wrap :: l -> Wrapper m l) x
```

But with or without the use of `ScopedTypeVariables`, I get the same error:

```
/tmp/PoC.hs:10:19:
    Could not deduce (Wrapper m ~ Wrapper m0)
    from the context (PoC m, Functor f)
      bound by the type signature for
                 upgrade :: (PoC m, Functor f) => f l -> f (Wrapper m l)
      at /tmp/PoC.hs:9:12-69
    NB: `Wrapper' is a type function, and may not be injective
    The type variable `m0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Expected type: l -> Wrapper m0 l
      Actual type: l -> Wrapper m l
    In the first argument of `fmap', namely
      `(wrap :: l -> Wrapper m l)'
    In the expression: fmap (wrap :: l -> Wrapper m l) x
    In an equation for `upgrade':
        upgrade x = fmap (wrap :: l -> Wrapper m l) x
```

But I don't understand where GHC binds this `m0`. Is "may not be injective" the core of the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-injectivity is the problem, indeed. Injectivity would allow GHC to know that if `f a ~ f b` then `a ~ b` but since you can have two `PoC m` instances with the same choice of `Wrapper m` type it's hard to know what `m` was after you've solved for what `Wrapper m` is.

You should be able to fix it by adding an input term to `wrap` which contains the `m` type parameter. This can be a proxy argument which is never evaluated

```
data Proxy a = Proxy

class PoC m where
  type Wrapper m :: * -> *
  wrap :: proxy m -> l -> Wrapper m l

instance PoC () where
  type Wrapper () = Maybe
  wrap _ = return

aUnit :: Proxy ()
aUnit = Proxy

upgrade :: (PoC m, Functor f) => proxy m -> f l -> f (Wrapper m l)
upgrade aProxy x = fmap (wrap aProxy) x
```

Comment: I feared as much. Proxies did come to mind, but I hoped that this could be fixed without them. Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, you need to find some way to put the m type information in the wrap signature unambiguously. There may be other cleverer solutions—maybe this is something closed type families can do.