# Ambiguous type with type families

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, type-families

I am running into a problem where GHC is not able to match `Foo t` and `Foo t0`, where it definitely looks to me like `t ~ t0`. Here's a minimal example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies   #-}

data Foobar :: * -> * where
  Foobar :: Foo t -> Foobar t

type family Foo a :: *

class Bar t where
  f :: Foobar t
  g :: Foo t
--  f = Foobar g
```

When uncommenting the last line, GHC complains:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Foo t’ with actual type ‘Foo t0’
NB: ‘Foo’ is a type function, and may not be injective
The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
Relevant bindings include f :: Foobar t (bound at test.hs:13:3)
In the first argument of ‘Foobar’, namely ‘g’
In the expression: Foobar g
```

I understand that `Foo` is not injective, but from my analysis GHC is never asked to come up with `t` from `Foo t`. It seems that the type `t` is lost in `Foobar g`, and so it can't match the inital `Foo t` and the new `Foo t0`. Is the context here not enough? Am I missing a case where `f = Foobar g` could not yield the correct result?

Any help appreciated!

N.B.: `ScopedTypeVariables` and explicit type signatures don't seem to help. Adding the constraint `a ~ Foo t` and using `a` instead as the type of `g` in `Foobar g` doesn't work either.

Looks a lot like: [ambiguous type error when using type families, and STV is not helping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838679/ambiguous-type-error-when-using-type-families-and-stv-is-not-helping?rq=1). I considered using a `Proxy`, but I feel like in this case GHC should be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I understand that `Foo` is not injective, but from my analysis GHC is never asked to come up with `t` from `Foo t`.

So, you realize the ambiguity. Let's make is explicit:

```
type instance Foo ()   = Bool
type instance Foo Char = Bool

instance Bar () where
   -- I omit the declaration for f
   g = True
instance Bar Char where
   g = False

main = print (g :: Bool)
```

Your problem in `f = Foobar g` is related to the ambiguity.

The crux is: the definition `f = Foobar g` does not imply that `g` much be picked in the same instance as `f`. It could refer to a different instance!

Consider

```
show (x,y) = "(" ++ show x ++ ", " ++ show y ++ ")"
```

Above, the RHS uses of `show` are from a different instance from the one where the LHS `show` is.

In your `f = Foobar g` line, GHC infers that `g :: Foo t` where `t` is the same index of the `f` instance. However, that is not enough to select an instance for `g`! Indeed, we might have `Foo t ~ Foo t0` for some other `t0`, hence `g` might refer to the `g` in the `t0` instance, causing an ambiguity error.

Note that your code is *rejected* by GHC 8 even if the last line is commented out, because the type of `g` is inherently ambiguous:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Foo t’ with actual type ‘Foo t0’
  NB: ‘Foo’ is a type function, and may not be injective
  The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
• In the ambiguity check for ‘g’
  To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
  When checking the class method: g :: forall t. Bar t => Foo t
  In the class declaration for ‘Bar’
```

We can follow the suggestion to make GHC 8 more lenient, like GHC 7. This will make your code type check, until we uncomment the last line.

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Foo t’ with actual type ‘Foo t0’
      NB: ‘Foo’ is a type function, and may not be injective
      The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
```

This is the same error you saw in GHC 7. 
In GHC 8, we have another luxury: we can *explicitly* choose the `t` for `g` as follows:

```
class Bar t where
  f :: Foobar t
  f = Foobar (g @ t)
  g :: Foo t
```

This requires a few more extensions to be turned on, of course. In GHC 7, you need a proxy to be able to select an instance unambiguously.

Comment: So even if I add `Foobar (g :: Foo t)`, the information of `t` will already be lost in `Foo t`, right? Is there another way of forcing the use of `g :: Foo t` where I mean `t` without making `Foo` injective and without using a `Proxy`?

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks. I'll go through GHC 8's new extensions and see what can be done. One minor comment, I don't think you mean injectivity in your last line (the point is for GHC to figure out that `t ~ t0` without injectivity).